# Python how to exclude exceptions from "catch all"

Tags: python, exception

Lets say I have this:

```
try:
    result = call_external_service()
    if not result == expected:
        raise MyException()
except MyException as ex:
    # bubble up
    raise ex
except Exception:
    # unexpected exceptions from calling external service
    do_some_logging()
```

Due to my limited python knowledge, I cannot think of an elegant way to bubble up the `MyException` exception, I was hoping I can do something like:

```
try:
    result = call_external_service()
    if not result == expected:
        raise MyException()
except Exception, exclude(MyException):
    # unexpected exceptions from calling external service
    do_some_logging()
```

Comment: I would probably just re-raise it if the type matches MyException

Comment: 1) What's wrong with your first code?  2) Why does your question start with "Let me elaborate more"? Are you continuing a conversation from somewhere else?

Comment: @NedBatchelder 1) I think catching it and re-raising it's not very straight-forward to read. 2) I thought the title was not clear enough so I said 'elaborate more', but I have updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you are wrapping too much code in your try block.  What about this?:

```
try:
    result = call_external_service()
except Exception:
    # unexpected exceptions from calling external service
    do_some_logging()

if result != expected:
    raise MyException()
```

Comment: it does make sense :)

Comment: I think the `if result != expected:` is a bit over simplified in my case, sometimes I need to access the `result` elements and `result` might not be the type I am after, I just have to put more try/except blocks then ...