# Python: statically detect unhandled exceptions

Tags: python, exception, static-analysis

I'm trying to write a highly-reliable piece of code in Python. The most common issue I run into is that after running for a while, some edge case will occur and raise an exception that I haven't handled. This most often happens when using external libraries - without reading the source code, I don't know of an easy way to get a list of all exceptions that might be raised when using a specific library function, so it's hard to know what to handle. I understand that it's bad practice to use catch-all handlers, so I haven't been doing that.

Is there a good solution for this? It seems like it should be possible for a static analysis tool to check that all exceptions are handled, but I haven't found one. Does this exist? If not, why? (is it impossible? a bad idea? etc) I especially would like it to analyze imported code for the reason explained above.

Comment: "it's bad practice to use catch-all handlers" **to ignore exceptions**. Our web service has an `except: log_exception(); attempt_recovery()` which wraps the main loop. `except: pass` is bad. The important bit is to log the exception and check those logs so you can write a better except case if something falls through the cracks.

Comment: wait so you’re not using, as you say, a ‘catch all’ handler? seems like that might be what you need here since, as you say, it isn’t easy getting a list of all the known exceptions. handling each one in a unique fashion, sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: "I understand that it's bad practice to use catch-all handlers, so I haven't been doing that." Where did you get this idea from? Is that rule you are imposing on yourself hurting you? Yes it is. Then why are you enforcing it on yourself?

Comment: It is nearly impossible to say without understanding the task at hand...
If you are doing some kind of numerical processing, this is called anomaly detection. The general idea is that as data comes in you develop a sense of the sample mean and standard deviation, and if new values come in that fall too far outside of this threshold you ignore or delete them in your processing.

Comment: This isn't even possible in Java, let alone Python.

Comment: Well, in some situations I really wouldn't want to use a catch all handler. For example, if I'm writing a function that will be used in other code, I wouldn't want it to catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception. I would much rather specifically catch the exceptions raised by eg. the library functions I'm using. I agree that catch-all might make sense at the top level, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"it's bad practice to use catch-all handlers" **to ignore exceptions**:

Our web service has an except which wraps the main loop.

```
except: 
    log_exception()
    attempt_recovery()
```

This is good, as it **notifies us** (necessary) of the unexpected error and then **tries to recover** (not necessary). We can then go look at those logs and figure out what went wrong so we can prevent it from hitting our general exception again.

---

This is what you want to **avoid**:

```
except:
    pass
```

Because it **ignores the error**... then you don't know an error happened and your data may be corrupted/invalid/gone/stolen by bears. Your server may be up/down/on fire. We have no idea because we ignored the exception.

---

Python doesn't require registering of what exceptions might be thrown, so there are no checks for all exceptions a module might throw, but most will give you some idea of what you should be ready to handle in the docs. Depending on your service, when it gets an unhandled exception, you might want to:

- Log it and crash
- Log it and attempt to continue
- Log it and restart

Notice a trend? The action changes, but you never want to ignore it.

Comment: I totally agree - see the comment I added on the question for why I might not want a catch-all, but instead would prefer to specifically catch individual exceptions in code that isn't top-level.

Comment: @zplizzi You can still catch all exceptions, inspect the exception, and raise any exceptions you explicitly don't want to catch. You could also [`except StandardError:`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StandardError), although that probably won't catch third party library exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Great question.

You can try approaching the problem statically (by, for instance, introducing a custom `flake8` rule?), but, I think, **it's a problem of testing and test coverage scope**. I would approach the problem by adding more "negative path"/"error handling" checks/tests to the places where third-party packages are used, introducing mock side effects whenever needed and monitoring coverage reports at the same time.

I would also look into [Mutation Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing) idea (check out [Cosmic Ray](http://cosmic-ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) Python package). I am not sure if mutants can be configured to also throw exceptions, but see if it could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! Hadn't heard of mutation testing, that is super cool. I would still prefer a static analysis tool, though. I would prefer to be told "your code definitely handles all exceptions that may be raised" versus "your code doesn't break in all the situations you thought to test (or which could be caught via mutation testing)". I think it's a fundamental difference - one approach checks that you are handling all possibilities somehow, and the other checks that you're handling some possibilities (but ensures you handle them correctly). Ideally both approaches would be combined.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to handle all exceptions, which is very hard as you described, why don't you catch all, but exclude some, for example the `KeyboardInterrupt` you mentioned in the comments?

[This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030716/python-how-to-exclude-exceptions-from-catch-all#27030766)